# Flutter Dialog: [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to fetch a value when a ListView Item in `Page1` is clicked:

```
...
child: ListTile(
        title: Text(title),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context, <String>[title]);
        },
      ),
...
```

Here, `title` is a String.

This is popped into Page 0:

```
...
CupertinoButton(
          child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
          onPressed: () async {
            var value = await Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => const Page1(),
              ),
            );
            print(value); // Added for debugging
            showNewDialog(context, value);
          },
...
    ),
```

And this is my `showNewDialog` method:

```
Future<dynamic> showNewDialog(
    BuildContext context, String name) {
  return showCupertinoDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(name),
        content: ...
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text("Cancel"),
            isDestructiveAction: true,
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            child: Text("Add"),
            onPressed: () {
              ...
              Navigator.pop(context, [...]);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

tldr; When I click a button on Page0, It opens Page1 and I can click a ListView item which basically sends the `title` (String) of that item back to Page0 so that I can create a `CupertinoAlertDialog` with `title` as the title of that Dialog.

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
#0      StatefulElement.state (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4926:44)
#1      Navigator.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2542:47)
#2      showCupertinoDialog (package:flutter/src/cupertino/route.dart:1291:20)
#3      showNewDialog (package:sid/utils.dart:37:10)
#4      _Page0State.build.<anonymous closure> (package:sid/page_0.dart:61:13)
```

The print value prints the right value, so there is no null value being passed in.

Also, I haven't used the '!' operator anywhere in my code. The error seems to point to `showCupertinoDialog`, which is weird.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can put the variable  static  and put the value that you want.

And after that when return to the main page u can check if the var is not empty

And if it's not than your condition :)